# Lock txt-files accessible via network, same user

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

1. PC Ubuntu 20.04, "common" folder set to "local network share", Samba entry for 2. PC user added
2. PC Ubuntu 22.04, get access to the "common" folder via Samba entry

Share two files

1. Calc ods-file :
   If the file is open on 1. PC and someone will open the file on 2. PC, he will get the Info :"Document file is locked ... a.s.o", all is OK.
2. txt-file, use gedit, same scenario as above :
   In this case I will get no information, whether the file is in use on a second PC. Further more, if the file will be modified on 2. PC, the permissions of the txt-file on 1. PC will be changed to "Allow executing file as program".

It is possible to get a mechanism, as like for Libre Office files ?

And also, that the permissions will not be changed ?

Comment: Its up to the application to implement filesystem locks unfortunately - stuff like notepad will just make a local copy and edit that. I've not seen permissions change like that in samba, but it can try to make some windows  - do you have any "force" stuff in your smb.conf, or interesting mask for the share?

Comment: The only what I did : sudo smbpasswd -a ...

Comment: smb.conf : create mask = 0700, directory mask = 0700, users profile : create mask = 0600, directory mask = 0700